# How to render conditionally (v-if) based on property if the object can be undefined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Note that **parent** is a firebase reference previously defined.

This is ok:

```
v-if="parent['key'] == foo"
```

But this:

```
v-if="parent['key'].child('somechild') == bar"
```

is throwing the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try guarding before referencing:

```
v-if="(parent['key'] && parent['key'].child('somechild')) == bar"
```

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior . The errors stopped but its not respecting the condition now 

`v-if="(parent['key'] && parent['key'].child('uid')) == user.uid" v-for="parent in buildings" `

Even if the **child('uid')** is different from the **user.uid** vue is rendering all **parents** in the database.

I have marked your answer correct anyway.

Comment: When `parent['key']` is `undefined`, the expression `(parent['key'] && parent['key'].child('uid'))` returns `undefined`. So, if it is being rendered, maybe `user.uid` is `undefined` or `null`. I would add, to debug, something like this somewhere: `child: {{ (parent['key'] && parent['key'].child('uid')) }} - user: {{ user.uid }}`, that way you'll see what exactly it considered equal.

Comment: Yes. the `user.uid` is undefined. I am using vuefire/firebase. Would you happen to know how I can get the current user to the reactive `data` from within a hook like `created` of `beforeCreate`?
I am doing it like this: `

`beforeCreate () {
       this.$store.dispatch('setUser');
       let user = this.$store.getters.getUser;
       console.log(user); // <<< this works 
    this.$set(this.user, 'uid', user.uid ) // <<< this doesn't 


  },`

Comment: i have created a question with all the info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760478/how-to-get-the-user-info-to-the-data-part-of-the-app-in-vue-js