# How to get the user info to the "data" part of the app in vue.js?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

Would you happen to know how to set the **user** to the currentUser?
I am using vuefire and firebase.
The **user.uid** is returning undefined.

```
 <td v-if="(building['key'] && building['key'].child('ownerId')) == user.uid">
            <p >{{building['.key']}} + {{user.uid}}</p>
</td>
```

this is the rest of my code:

```
import firebase,{ db, usersRef, buildingsRef } from '../firebase-config';
import { store } from '../store/store';

export default {

  firebase() { 
    // from my understanding this just gives me a quick access to the Refs and a short nomenclature
    return { 
    users: usersRef,  
    buildings: buildingsRef, 
    }
  },
  name: 'buildings',
  data () {
    return {
      user: "",
      building: {
        name: '',
        address: '',
        comments: '',
        ownerId: '',
      },
    }
  },
```

I am trying to do it through the store in the beforeCreate hook:

```
  beforeCreate () {
       this.$store.dispatch('setUser');
       let user = this.$store.getters.getUser;
       console.log(user); // this works!!!
      this.$set(this.user, 'uid', user.uid )
  }   
},
```

If instead I set the **user** in create hook like this:

```
  created () {
       this.$store.dispatch('setUser');
       let user = this.$store.getters.getUser;
       console.log(user); // this works!!!
      this.$set(this.user, 'uid', user.uid )
    }
```

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue, the **state** (aka `data` properties) is [initialized between the `beforeCreate` and `created`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L4613-L4617) hooks.

So any change you do to `data` in `beforeCreate` is **lost**.

Change your hook to `created`

```js
created() {                         // changed this line
  this.$store.dispatch('setUser');
  let user = this.$store.getters.getUser;
  console.log(user); // this works!!!
  this.$set(this.user, 'uid', user.uid)
}
```

Comment: I had tried that and it doesn't work. I am getting this error: 
 `[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: ... [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'uid' in " ... TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'uid' in 
    at VueComponent.set [as $set] (vue.esm.js?efeb:1035)
    at VueComponent.created (buildings.vue?3efe:136)
    at callHook (vue.esm.js?efeb:2921)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.esm.js?efeb:4630)
    at new VueComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:4798)
    at createComponentIns...`

Comment: Can you paste that error in the question? It is quite unreadable in the comment (with the line breaks gone).

Comment: In data, declare `user` as an object instead of `""`:   `data () {
    return {
      user: {},`.